# Laravel queue fopen: No such file or directory

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-5, queue

I am developing a project on Laravel 5.5 which has PDF generation feature using `niklasravnsborg\LaravelPdf` library.

The PDF file is being generated when at least one of the following two events happens:

1. When the user presses on "Generate PDF" in the web view.
2. Automatically, using "Queue", which will generate the PDF file and send an email to the user automatically.

The PDF generation in the first event is working fine, but in the second one, it is not.

During the generation process, it shows the following error multiple times

`PHP Warning:  fopen(path/to/image/file.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in path\mpdf\mpdf\mpdf.php on line 11812`

And when it finishes, all the images in the PDF file does not appear.

Can this be related to one of the service providers that does not initialize a crucial component for the PDF generation, but it does not initialize it when the `App::runningInConsole()` returns `true`?

Comment: seems like in second condition the image path isn't accessible so try changing it to 777 permissions....make sure you access the correct path of image

Comment: All permissions are granted for the directory.